# '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' in functions and using lambda in apply

Tags: python, pandas, function, apply

I am trying to define a function then apply the function to the dataframe called reviews.

```
def stars(country, points):
    if country == 'Canada':
        return 3
    elif points >= 95:
        return 3
    elif points >= 85:
        return 2
    else:
        return 1

star_ratings = reviews.apply(lambda x: stars(x['points'], x['country']), axis=1)
```

I get the error:

```
<ipython-input-46-42befd5aa1a8> in stars(country, points)
      2     if country == 'Canada':
      3         return 3
----> 4     elif points >= 95:
      5         return 3
      6     elif points >= 85:

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

How should I rectify the code to make it work? Also, is the use of lambda here correct/common practice? Thanks!

Comment: what is unclear about the error? Your data obviously contains `str`. Just convert them to numbers first.

Comment: Generally remapping based on conditions is done with `np.select` over the lambda. Like in [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19913659/15497888)

Comment: You are sending the variables in reversed order than in the function definition.

Comment: What is the data type of the points column? Is it a string? It really helps to include a small sample dataframe that exhibits the question so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `point` is in `string` so, you're getting this error. But you can solve this by changing that `string` into `integer`. And in function you are sending wrongly, it should be `points` and `country` rather `country` and `points`.

```
def stars(points,country):
    if country == 'Canada':
        return 3
    elif int(points) >= 95:
        return 3
    elif int(points) >= 85:
        return 2
    else:
        return 1

star_ratings = reviews.apply(lambda x: stars(x['points'], x['country']), axis=1)
```

Comment: How do you know that `points` is a string? OP doesn't give us enough information to know.

Comment: Given that the inputs were reversed it's likely that the `int` conversion is unnecessary and that this is just a typo by incorrectly mapping function arguments.

Comment: @HenryEcker How do you know that is unnecessary? Is there enough information to know that? So, I had gave answer which will work in any condition. And Yeah! I had explained OP is wrong in function argument and changed in code too.

Comment: @tdelaney Yeah! OP hadn't provided enough information so, I had gave information for either condition.

Comment: If the points column is a string, it would likely be better to fix the dataframe rather than trying to make up for it in support functions.

Comment: @tdelaney I agree with you. But it isn't clear.... And I believe OP's problem is already solved.